# Delete a node from a linked list, given the index position, but starting from the end

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

In my quest to learn about algorithms from interview questions, I did find this really interesting.

Basically the question was asking to remove a node at index, but starting from the end of the linked list. And in one loop.

I was thinking that you need 2 loops, one to know the lenght of the list, another to delete the node, starting at the end, but then I thought that a linked list is sequential anyway, so one loop should work.

How would you approach this in the most simple way? I was trying with python; you can create a simple list and do the operation in 4 lines; but if you are in an interview, they usually want you to do "all by hand" without using language shortcuts.

Comment: use 2 pointers p1 and p2. in the loop, first advance only p1 by index times. Then advance both till end of loop, i.e till p1 reaches end of list. by this time, p2 will point to the node at distance index from the end, and you can delete it.

Comment: I see, so the first pointer keep track of the global index, while the second start at index -n? I didn't think about doing this; that's a really good way to do one loop!

Comment: thats right, watch out for off-by-1 errors in this one, make sureyou are deleting the right node and handling the case when length of the list is smaller than given index position.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ListNode* removeNthFromEnd(struct ListNode* head, int n) {
    struct ListNode *temp = head;
    int length = 0;
while(temp->next!=NULL){
    temp = temp->next;
    length++;
}
temp = head;
while(length!= n+1){
    temp = temp->next;
    length--;
}
temp->next = temp->next->next;
return head;
```

}

EDIT:
   initially i am calculating the length of the linked list using first while loop and then i am decrementing that length till i reach the node prior to the mentioned node using the second while loop, then i am simply deleting the node  and returning the head;

Comment: are you asking a question or answering to the question? If answering then please add some explanation alongside.

Comment: it's an answer, i will add the explanation :)